# receiving emails via ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix

i followed the instruction here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix

i have a domain name name my-domain.com with hostnames www and @ pointing to my IP address. so how can i have emails sent to name@my-domain.com come to the server?

ideally i'd like to pipe them into some scripts and process them from there.

Comment: Thank you for sharing, but what is your question ?

Comment: how can i have emails sent to name@my-domain.com come to the server?

Answer (score 1):

So normally you have an MX record pointing to your IP.

Postfix : You can do this by configuring your virtual domains and by using a vmail or maildir format.

One has many options to configure this either with mysql or simple textfiles.

Since this is too much to summarize in one post I suggest you take a look at [this tutorial](http://workaround.org/ispmail/squeeze). Even though it is for Debian, it should work the same with ubuntu.

Comment: i just learned my server is technically working.. my attempt to email it was rejected: User unknown in local recipient table;. i guess that's another issue altogether, however

Comment: actually it's not, if you follow the tutorial you will come across all of these problems. It is because postfix can not find the user because you have not configured a database.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you will need to do is set up an MX record on your DNS for your domain, so other servers know what server handles the mail for that domain

Use this to check if you currently have an MX record:

http://www.mxtoolbox.com/

And the BIND docs on Ubuntu will tell you about the different DNS record types if you need to add it:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BIND9ServerHowto

Once you've got that set up you should see stuff in mail.log when you send emails to the domain